# Printing a styled table - R

Tags: r

I have a code that previously printed the models from glms. I now want to run it after running
`confint` and I can't..

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(foreign)
library(mfx)
library(jtools)
library(skimr)
library(kableExtra)
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
library(dotwhisker)
library(MASS)

flights <- nycflights13::flights
flights<- sample_n (flights, 500)
m1<- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ dep_time + origin+ air_time+ distance , data = flights)

kbl <- function (df) {
  cat("\n\n")
  df2<-kable(df) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options =     c("striped", "condensed"))
  print(df2)
  cat("\n\n")
}

m2<- summ(m1, exp = T)
kbl(m2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code produces the following error message:

```
kbl(m2)

#Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
#  cannot coerce class ‘c("summ.glm", "summ")’ to a data.frame
```

Your function `kbl()` uses `kable()` function from `kableExtra` package. Based on its documentation (you can check it by running `?kable` ), it requires an R object which is typically a matrix or data frame as the input. If the input is not one, it tries to coerce it to a data frame. However,  `m2` is neither a matrix nor a data frame and it cannot be coerced to a data frame so that it is not suitable to be the input for `kbl()`.

If you want to print only the table in `m2`, you can try:

```
kbl(m2$coeftable)
```

`m2$coeftable` is a matrix so it is suitable as the input for `kbl()`. You can check it by `is.matrix(m2$coeftable)`.